# Record teams online meetings - Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using Microsoft graph api to create online meetings on Microsoft Teams and everything work well, but now, I need to register this meetings to auto record always when the meeting start, and then, get this record and play on my platform. Someone know how can I perform this?

I've read a lot of articles and found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Policy-based recording enables automatic recording of calling & meetings.

Could you please take a look at Introduction to [Teams policy-based recording for callings & meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy) docs? Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: it seems like i have to associate an user or record every meeting, but that is not necessaryly what i need, i just want to record some meetings that my aplication has registered on behalf a user, has anyway to apply this polices to especific meetings? 
Has how to add a tag to a meeting or something on this way?

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little late coming, but hopefully it helps someone else out there.

In the /onlineMeetings POST call, at the same level as the subject you can add an automaticallyRecord parameter and set it to true.

That call returns the url of the meeting for participants to join. When they join the meeting it automatically records. This call also returns the threadId.

You can then use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/Recordings/children to return a list of the recordings in the user's One Drive and search through the recordings from that meeting and get the latest one.